# Combine 2 Conditional Split Cases into 1

Tags: ssis, conditional-statements, conditional-split

I have 1 SSIS Conditional Split with 2 conditions, which I need to combine. Both conditions are looking for the same date.

`[DateFinished] > (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"2016-09-01"`

`[DateTBFinish] > (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"2016-09-01"`

I have tried

`[DateFinished]  &&  [DateTBFinish] > (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"2016-09-01"`

However, this errors.

I would appreciate any help with getting the correct structure to make this work.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I like to weed out my bad records and let the leftovers (good records) move on. Simply change your signs to <=.

Comment: You can also run them back together through a union all. This would be a scenario if you had 5 tests and test 1-3 go one way and 4-5 go another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[DateFinished] > (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"2016-09-01" && [DateTBFinish] > (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"2016-09-01"
```

Comment: No problem - please mark the answer as correct if it is working. :)